# How do I make an exit button in npyscreen?

Tags: python, npyscreen

What I want is basically a regular npyscreen.Form, but I want the "OK" button to say "Exit".

It appears that you can't change the name of the button in the regular npyscreen.Form, so I tried subclassing npyscreen.ButtonPress:

```
import npyscreen

class ExitButton(npyscreen.ButtonPress):
    def whenPressed(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

class MainForm(npyscreen.FormBaseNew):
    def create(self):
        self.exitButton = self.add(ExitButton, name="Exit", relx=-12, rely=-3)

class App(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm, name="My Form")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App().run()
```

The button shows up, but when you click it, you get `'ExitButton' object has no attribute 'parentApp'`.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edwin's right, use `self.parent.parentApp` not `self.parentApp`.

To exit the app use `switchForm(None)` instead of `setNextForm(None)`.

```
def whenPressed(self):
    self.parent.parentApp.switchForm(None)
```

reference: a [post by npyscreen's author](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/npyscreen/zkW-_hXeJ08) confirms this works as expected.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, it behaves the same as your answer

Comment: When would one use self.parentApp, and when would it be self.parent.parentApp? [Documentation](http://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/application-objects.html?highlight=parentapp) mentions self.parentApp, but I don't see any mention of self.parent.parentApp.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the most elegant solution but it works, first of all to access `setNextForm` from `ExitButton` you should do it as follows: `self.parent.parentApp.setNextForm(None)`. Even correcting this does not work, I used `sys.exit(0)` to exit.

```
import npyscreen
import sys


class ExitButton(npyscreen.ButtonPress):
    def whenPressed(self):
        sys.exit(0)

class MainForm(npyscreen.FormBaseNew):
    def create(self):
        self.exitButton = self.add(ExitButton, name="Exit", relx=-12, rely=-3)


class App(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm, name="My Form")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App().run()
```

Comment: This works well for me (`sys.exit(0)`).  I expected that some ncurses cleanup operations might not work in this case, but the terminal seems to reset to its original settings...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to change the name of the OK Button. Modify in the desired form class the attribute

```py
OK_BUTTON_TEXT='YourCustomNameOKButton'
```

Reference: built-in help for FORM class.

Answer (score 0):

use `self.parent.parentApp` since `ExitButton` resides inside the `Form`, and Form has access to `parentApp`

use `switchForm()` instead of `setNextForm()`

```
class ExitButton(npyscreen.ButtonPress):
    def whenPressed(self):
        self.parent.parentApp.switchForm(None)
```